# How can I create configure extension for ILoggingBuilder in ASP .Net Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, asp.net-core

I use Asp .NET Core 2.2 and need log in file. And tried with ILoggerFactory:

```
 loggerFactory.AddProvider(new MyOwnFileLogProvider());
```

But:

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole();//This method is obsolete and will be removed in a future version.
```

Ok, reject all factories and used:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseKestrel()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                });
```

How can I create configure extension for ILoggingBuilder for file logging?

```
logging.AddFile();
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly do you want. The signature for extension method AddFile? The implementation of extension method? If you just need to log into file try one of logging frameworks like [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/download/) or [log4n](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logger factory methods are deprecated in favor of the newer logging builder which fully facilitates the dependency injection container. Creating a logger builder extension for your own logger provider is not difficult though.

You basically just need to add an `ILoggerProvider` to the service collection:

```
public static ILoggingBuilder AddConsole(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, CustomLoggerProvider>();

    return builder;
}
```

Instead of resolving your provider through dependency injection, you can also register an instance directly. There is also a built-in extension method [`AddProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggingbuilderextensions.addprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that does exactly that. So you can use that as well:

```
public static ILoggingBuilder AddConsole(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
{
    builder.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider>());

    return builder;
}
```

That should make the usage *very similar* to the one utilizing the `ILoggerFactory`.